# How does android (stock) calculate the number of bars representing mobile signal quality?

Tags: notification-bar, network-signal

I am interested in how Android (assuming unmodified AOSP code) calculates the number of bars representing mobile signal quality?

Also, if you know the place in code where this is done, I would appreciate that info as well.